# XmlDataContractSerializer fails on IEnumerable yields

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xml-serialization

I have a .Net Core controller's action which returns a list of products:

```
public IActionResult GetProductFeed([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ProductFeedFilterModelBinder))] ProductFeedFilter filter)
{
    ...
    //return Ok(new List<ProductFeedItem> { new ProductFeedItem() });
    return Ok(Test());
}

private IEnumerable<ProductFeedItem> Test()
{
    yield return new ProductFeedItem();
}
```

I have also enabled the xml data contract serializer:

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());

    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv") { Charset = "utf-8" });
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
}).AddControllersAsServices();
```

If the method returns a list of product feed items, then it works fine, however for the yield method I am getting an exception that the type ProductFeedController+<< Test >>d__3 cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute.

This works well for the json output. Should I enable something on the serializer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DTOs (serialization objects) don't usually play nicely with games like `IEnumerable<T>`. Have you considered just exposing a `List<T>` instead?

Comment: Hi @Marc, I have, however the underlying processing in this action method involves getting stream from Solr to process larger amount of data, so I was hoping to preserve that streaming to the output.